# Python regex search and replace all print statement

Tags: python, regex, file

My sample code is written in a file containing several print statements,

```
def get_address(cls,latitude,longitude):
    try:
        geolocator = GoogleV3()
        location = geolocator.reverse(latitude,longitude)
        print location
        print location.address
        print "location"
        print("location")
        return (location.address)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Am using regex to delete all the print statements (except print e) from this code,
my code:

```
import re
regex = r"print[/s]?[^e]?(.)+"
try:
    print (re.sub(regex, "AA", str))
except Exception as e:
    print e
old_file=open("views.py")
new_file=open("new_text.py", "w")
for line in old_file:
    new_line = re.sub(regex, "", line)
    new_file.write(new_line)
old_file.close()
new_file.close()
```

my code is written in views.py, an new code in new_text.py, after running this script, **print e** in exception also deleted, which cause syntax error. Is there any good way to delete all print statements except **print e** and save code in same file.

Comment: Don’t reinvent the wheel. Use [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html), bundled with the Python installation, to update your code to Python 3.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy. That doesn't seem relevant, since the OP wants to keep `print e` in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with negative lookahead pattern. Changing your pattern to

```
print[/s]?(?! e)(.)+
```

Will do the work. The `(?!)` - is negative lookahead assertion, match only if the next chars are NOT matched

For example,

```
>>> p = re.compile('print[/s]?(?! e)(.)+')
>>> 
>>> re.match(p, 'print abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x028745E0>
>>> re.match(p, 'print e')
>>>
```

If you want to support multiple e's, you can define it as follows:

```
>>> re.match('print (?!e{1,5}$)\D+', 'print ele')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000042904A8>
>>> re.match('print (?!e{1,5}$)\D+', 'print ee')
>>> re.match('print (?!e{1,5}$)\D+', 'print eee')
```

This will match 1 to 5 times of e (print eeeee). You can change it to whatever num you want.

Comment: Thanks, but this not working for all cases, not working for print ee

Comment: @GauravRathore Well, if you also want to keep `print ee` you need to edit your question and explain exactly what you want to delete and keep.

Comment: How many variations of `print e` you want to cover? two e's? three e's? infinity?

Comment: @GauravRathore I've added another solution, to match multiple e's as the variable

Comment: Thanks Vinny, your previous code is working, but there is one more complication, i also want to ignore print(e), print (e) and print e, but not print ee or print 'e'.
replace everything except print(e), print (e) and print e

Comment: well, i'll help you with the `print (e)` part and let you match the rest of the requirements: `>>> re.match('print (?!(\()?e{1,5}(\))?$)\D+', 'print (e)')` - this will skip `print (e)` as well as `print e`

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Since there are only three exceptions, a simple solution is to skip them:

```
allowed_prints = ['print(e)', 'print (e)', 'print e']
for line in old_file:
    stripped = line.strip()
    # or, if you want to account for comments in the print line:   
    # stripped = line.split('#')[0].strip()
    if stripped.startswith('print') and stripped not in allowed_prints:
        continue
    new_file.write(line)
```